# How can I make a shortcut key to disable the mouse pad?

Tags: keyboard, shortcut-keys, touchpad

I have a dm3t laptop and when im using the keyboard I frequently accidentally touch it and cause some mouse event. How can I make a shortcut key that toggles the mousepad on and off?

Comment: In Ubuntu 18.04 [`gsettings` command](https://askubuntu.com/a/1072472/853796) can be used to toggle the touchpad.

Answer (score 3):

If you are using Synaptics Touchpad, you can toggle the touchpad on and off by using [`synclient`](http://linux.die.net/man/1/synclient). To turn the pad off, run `synclient TouchpadOff=1`, and to turn it back on use `synclient TouchpadOff=0`.

You can set up keyboard shortcuts by System > Preferences > Keyboard Shortcuts.

If you're not sure if you are using Synaptics Touchpad, run `xinput list`, and one of the entries will mention Synaptics if you are.

Answer (score 2):

You could use [Touchfreeze](http://launchpad.net/ubuntu/+source/touchfreeze)

By using the following command you can install it from terminal

`sudo apt-get install touchfreeze`

This application automatically disables touchpad temporarily when you type something and also enables it back after you stopped typing. It has a GUI and some configuration options like a customizable switch-delay.

So you'll need no shortcut-key.