# Disable touchpad with fn key

Tags: touchpad, asus, ubuntu-gnome

when I press <kbd>Fn</kbd> key + button for touchpad, I get popup as you can see on image, but touchpad is still working.

[image]

When I go to the Setting > Mouse & Touchpad, touchpad is disabled. I check to turn on, and uncheck again, and touchpad is disabled. Can you tell me how I can fix it? I want control tochpad with my default touchpad button with <kbd>Fn</kbd> key. My OS is Ubuntu Gnome 16.04 and laptop Asus N56VJ. Thanks.

Comment: https://askubuntu.com/questions/844151/enable-disable-touchpad/874865#874865 might help you.

Comment: I got  error unable to find device .. so this script not works for me

Answer (score 0):

The touchpad is affected by hardware which is controlled by GNOME shell.
Try to reset all keys and touchpad settings using

```
gsettings reset-recursively org.gnome.desktop.peripherals.touchpad
```

or

```
gsettings reset-recursively org.gnome.settings-daemon.peripherals.touchpad
```

You can also use `dconf` to reset touchpad settings to default settings

```
dconf reset -f /org/gnome/desktop/peripherals/touchpad/
```

For more details prefer the manual which can be obtained using

```
man gsettings
```