# Ubuntu 18.04, can't disable laptop touchpad on Dell Latitude E5520

Tags: touchpad, dell

Dell Latitude E5520.

<kbd>Fn</kbd>+<kbd>F5</kbd> always shows a "disabled touchpad" symbol, but it remains active.

Comment: have you tried installing "Gnome Tweaks" and the options with in it?

Comment: yes I have it, there is option to disable touchpad while typing (which does not work)  - can't see any way that this app helps.

Comment: I have recently installed Ubuntu 18.04 on my friends Dell laptop.. While doing something in tweaks.. I remember once I switch on.. I could not use touchpad at all. I connected external mouse and then turned off the same button then it worked. Rite now I am at office not with Ubuntu to check it. Thought it might help you.

Answer (score 0):

As a work-around you can use a gnome-shell extension:

1. [Toggle Touchpad](https://extensions.gnome.org/extension/935/toggle-touchpad/)
2. [Touchpad Indicator](https://extensions.gnome.org/extension/131/touchpad-indicator/) - that's the one I prefer

Comment: as a workaround, I assigned ctrl F5 and alt-F5 to xinput set-prop "AlpsPS/2 ALPS GlidePoint" "Device Enabled" 1 and xinput set-prop "AlpsPS/2 ALPS GlidePoint" "Device Enabled" 0   -  So workaround exists, but if I got the real thing to work, then it would also auto-disable while typing.

Answer (score 0):

Use user [Almas Dusal](https://askubuntu.com/users/433961/almas-dusal)'s [bash script for toggling the touchpad device](https://askubuntu.com/a/874865/346365).

I had this problem with my Dell Inspiron. <kbd>Fn</kbd>+<kbd>F3</kbd> used to work fine in 16.04 Xenial Xerus, but after dist-upgrading to 18.04, all I got was the  popping "*disabled touch-pad symbol*" followed by no noticeable change in system behavior.

Above script worked like a charm.